# Does Laravel 8 require PHP 8.1?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8, laravel-9

So.. I developed a project with **Laravel 9**, then I had to upload it to my client's server by FTP ( which was slow and painful ) to find out only afterwards that my client's server PHP version could not go over 8.0. I tried to open the project live link ( to where I uploaded ) and the **composer platform check was telling me my project had dependencies on PHP 8.1 and that my version is 8.0.**

***So I tried tweaking the platform check php file to disable this check, to see if it would work anyways but no,  the project was throwing errors.***

**So I decided to downgrade to laravel 8**, because after searching around I read that laravel 8 did not need php 8.1.
I guess I read some wrong information because after tweaking my project to downgrade to laravel 8 and uploading again (painfully by ftp), **the platform check was again telling me that my project needed PHP 8.1.**

So **I disabled again this platform check by editing/tweaking the platform check php file, to see if it would work anyway, and it did work.** So all good. but then today I was learning how to check which composer packages had dependencies on a specific php version, and in the process I found out (if I'm not wrong) that **laravel 8 has package dependencies that depend on PHP 8.1 ?**

***Is there a table somewhere I can check which Laravel versions depend on which PHP versions or do I have to run some commands on each project to check these dependencies?***

Like in the images below:

[image: laravel packages dependent on php 8.1]

Thanks !

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases shows the versions and PHP requirements, and Laravel 8 is fine on PHP 8.0. But one of the other packages you have in your composer.json may not be compatible. Make sure you delete your full vendor folder before you run `composer install` again. I would also suggest setting up local environment for easier testing, so you don't have to keep uploading it.

Comment: Please share more details, like the current state of your `composer.json`. And yes, there might be packages that require at least PHP 8.1 - but it should be possible to use prior versions of these packages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laravel 9 does not require PHP 8.1 it requires PHP 8.0.2

If this a shared project and someone else with PHP 8.1 generated the `composer.lock` file (or indeed you locally have PHP 8.1 but the server has 8.0) you might end up with packages that require PHP 8.1. Composer resolves and installs packages based on the locally installed PHP version.

You can override this behaviour and ensure everyone gets package deps based on the PHP version you expect to have on production if you use the [platform](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) config option in your composer.json e.g. add this to your `composer.json`

```
"config": {
  "platform": {
     "php": "8.0.2" 
  }
}
```

Then run

```
composer update
```

this should try to fix your package versions to ones that work with PHP 8

Comment: Ok amazing! This was my preferred solution! I added the configuration you recommended, I deleted my vendor folder and also my composer.lock, I installed again ( composer install ) - even on a php 8.1 container ( locally ) and then after I ran "composer depends php | grep 8.1" I no longer get any rows! meaning all is good now! Also I have tested on the production server that has the php 8.0 and it worked and composer gave me no warning! thanks alot!!

Answer (score 2):

Short response no, Laravel 8 requires PHP >= 7.3
From [Server Requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment)
But, since you downgraded it is possible that some php packages require newer php versions no matter the version chosen for Laravel.

Some hints:

- Change dependencies (packages) version, probably downgrade them.
- Delete the vendor folder.
- Delete composer.lock
- Run composer install

Checking your screenshot: with symfony the downgrade will not break anything.
But, check the other package/s ie: tojsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles requirements.

Comment: Deleting the vendor folder + composer.lock also helped me get things into place + adding the "config"."platform" setting in composer.json. But my downgrade was on a whole different folder / installation and then I added my models.. migrations manually, but thumbs up :)

Comment: the reason for packages depending on php 8.1 - with laravel 8 - was because of my local environment had php 8.1, but adding the config.platform setting in composer.json fixed it.

Comment: what... mean from >= 7.3 is more than 7.3 or equal...
not just equal to 7.3