# Laravel black page - Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger

Tags: laravel

After following [the instruction](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-on-000webhost/127323) to deploy my Laravel app on 000webhost.com, i got a black page with server error on console and when i look to Laravel logs i see:

```
laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at /storage/ssd3/245/19242245/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:207)

laravel.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected token ")" {"exception":"[object] (ParseError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected token \")\" at /storage/ssd3/245/19242245/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php:636)
```

All works on local server.

Laravel 9

Use PHP8.0 on 000webhost

Comment: Don't use 000webhost, you can't use `.env` or the operative system's environment variables, that is an absolute NO-NO even for remote development environments...

Comment: Oh. Ok then, it's was just for demo site.

Comment: Sounds like you installed your dependencies on a machine that had PHP 8.1 and ended up with dependencies that require 8.1 to work. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73585348/does-laravel-8-require-php-8-1/73585628#73585628